# In UWP app, where should html assets be stored in the assets directory?

Tags: c++-winrt

In a UWP app using cppwinrt I want to use WebView to display contents of a book kept in the Assets folder. I read that it is necessary to reference an html asset this way for use as a Uri argument to the Navigate method in web view:

```
TheWebView.Navigate(Uri(L"ms-appx-web:///SampleBook/PageOne.html"));
```

This produces an empty view, while

```
TheWebView.Navigate(Uri(L"ms-appx:///SampleBook/PageOne.html"));
```

crashes. Msdn says that for files "that will be loaded into the web compartment" one must use ms-appx-web, and I've seen mention that this is a security issue. But does that mean the files are in a special location within the project - i.e. not merely in the Assets folder - or does it only mean that the path must begin with ms-appx-web independent of the file's location? "Web compartment" is not explained but seems to be not a location but rather a classification of the type of resource. At any rate, neither of the above approaches works, so I'm curious to know the recommended way to store and access a collection of html files in the package. In the assets folder? A special folder within assets? In Solution Explorer the html file is listed, "content" is True, and the file is Included In Project. Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm trying to figure out the recommended way as well.

Comment: ShrimpCrackers, sorry, no - I haven't gotten back to that part of the project yet and no one has offered a suggestion. Seems to me the answer might have to do with finding an answer to the question: what is a 'web compartment' -?

Comment: ShrimpCrackers, I got it. Silly error on my part: the path was wrong. I have the folder with html content in the Assets directory, but that ms-appx-web does not go to assets - the required path was ms-appx-web///Assets/SampleBook/PageOne.html. The term "web compartment" in the docs has no meaning I've been able to discover - seems to refer just to any kind html content. Now I just need to find out why the videos in my content won't play.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake: ms-appx-web does not point to the assets folder, but to its parent. The correct path for content of this type would be ms-appx-web///Assets/SampleBook/PageOne.html. The reference to material to be "loaded to the web compartment" apparently is just a way of saying: stuff to be loaded with WebViewer.